# Required to enter password every time I want to save a file in VSCode

Tags: permissions, visual-studio-code

As I read around from a few threads here. I shouldn't run VSCode as root because it is dangerous. But every time I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, I need to go down to the bottom right and click run as administrator and enter my password. Not just once, but every time I save a file. Even the same file that I already just saved 2 seconds ago.

I'm saving the files in a folder on my desktop: `~/Desktop/github`.

Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Where do you attempt to save the files?

Comment: Just a folder on the desktop thomas@thomas-desktop:~/Desktop/github

Answer (score 9):

Check ownership and permissions for that file.

```
ls -l
```

It will give you a list of files, their permissions and ownership. Here is an example:
[file list screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Qoc.png) If your user doesn't have ownership you can change it using :

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER FOLDER_NAME
```

Or, if you are in a user group (like *www-data*) and your user group owns files but you can't do changes, you have to change the permission level to 775 by doing this:

```
sudo chmod 775 FILE_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not own the directory "github"

Open a terminal

```
cd Desktop
chown $USER:$USER github
```

... and you can save files in that directory. But do have a think about it 1st: who or what created it? Maybe you are not supposed to use that directory? Is it called github for a specific reason? I would assume VSCode would use "Documents".

Answer (score 1):

## Running VSCode as Root on Wayland

If your distro uses Wayland rather than X11 than running vscode as sudo will not work.

The only solution I came to after a fair bit of research was to create a bash script that uses the known and accepted workaround xhost root.

Save the following script into /home/your-username/bin (create if doesn't exist), also ensure you add that folder to your path. I've named the file containing the script **wsudocode**

**NOTE: This script assumes your user-data-dir for root vscode is `/home/your-username/.vscode-root`**

```
#!/bin/bash
#small script to enable root access to x-windows system 
xhost +SI:localuser:root
sudo code --user-data-dir=/home/$USER/.vscode-root --verbose $1 > /dev/null 2>&1
#disable root access after application terminates
xhost -SI:localuser:root
#print access status to allow verification that root access was removed
xhost
```

### Usage

`wsudocode [target file or directory path]`

### Notes

For some reason that seems ridiculous I could only get vscode to run as sudo this way with the --verbose option, hence why that is in the script.

Also remember that VSCode will save all files with root permissions when run as root, this may be unintended and thus you would have to change ownership and likely permissions of saved files if this is the case.

Adapted from jeepr's generic solution here https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/5eb633/solution_running_graphical_app_with_sudo_in/

Comment: VSCode should not run as root, there is no reason to do that and it will only cause all kinds of security and permission problems.

Comment: Yeah we've all heard the 'don't run as root speech before' but some people have reasons and are willing to take the risk... If it's for an isolated development/muck-around environment what does it matter... I personally rarely use it unless I want syntax highlighting and simpler tools for editing a more complex system file.

Comment: doesn't work for me on ubuntu 22.04, nothing pops up and sudocode returns in ~300ms

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having problems with this after following some of the steps above, please double check your VSCode extensions. For me it really wasn't VSCode dealing with permissions errors but rather the SFTP VSCode extension I had installed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove read-only permissions from the app folder as follows:

```
sudo chmod -R 7777 <project_folder_name>
```